# Setting the spacing within table

Tags: css, css-tables

I have the following code in my CSS:

```
#cartTable {
width:100%;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0px;

}

#cartTable td {
text-align: center;
color:#ffffff;
font-family: 'AllerBoldItalic', Arial, serif;
font-size: 14px;
border-top:1px solid;
border-bottom:1px solid;
border-color:#c8a300;   
}

#cartTable td img{
 position: relative;
top: 10px;   
}

.cartText{
 padding-bottom:10px;
}

#cartTable input[type="text"] {
width:50px;
height:15px;
vertical-align:bottom;
margin-bottom:5px;
 }

#cartTable select {
width:100px;
height:25px;
position: relative;
top: 10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

My problem is that the text which has class of cartText is sticked on the bottom of the row, while I would like to be on the same height as the images or my select and textbox elements has.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line-height so it's the same as the font-size